# Jmeter Variable from CSV

Tags: csv, testing, jmeter

I am running a Jmeter Test Plan with an HTTP Request, to test the performance of a web service.

In my test, I need a variable named REF to be changed in the body data of my HTTP Request. 
REF can have 3000 values. So I have created a CSV file with all these 3000 values, a CSV Data Set Config, and a parameter in Jmeter named REF, and I use it in my HTTP Request like that :

```
<measure>
    <measureRef id="${REF}"></measureRef>
    <measureTime>${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss)}</measureTime>
    <measureVal>
        <value>${__Random(1,100,)}</value>
    </measureVal>
</measure>
```

As you can see it in this XML, I use the functions time and Random of Jmeter to have different requests everytime I run the test plan.

I would like yo run the test plan automatically for all the 3000 values of REF. To do that, I tried to configure the thread group like this : Number of Threads = 3000 and Loop Control = 1.

The problem is that the test takes 3 minutes to be done. So I would like to know if there is another way to do. The thing is that I need the test to be done for all the differents 3000 values in my CSV, and I don't see another way to do. I tried to put another measure in my Body Data, like this :

```
<measure>
    <measureRef id="${REF}"></measureRef>
    <measureTime>${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss)}</measureTime>
    <measureVal>
        <value>${__Random(1,100,)}</value>
    </measureVal>
</measure>
<measure>
    <measureRef id="${REF}"></measureRef>
    <measureTime>${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss)}</measureTime>
    <measureVal>
        <value>${__Random(1,100,)}</value>
    </measureVal>
</measure>
```

But the value of REF that is used this the same in the two measures, and what I want is to have different values picked in the CSV.

I also tried to configure the Thread Group like this : Number of Threads = 1 and Loop Control = 3000. But it's not working, I have a lot of errors...

I want the test to be runned quickly because to test my web service, I'd like to inject the 3000 values every 1 minute (by using a Flow Control Action maybe). And if the test runs in 3 minutes, I would be too long, and all the values would not be tested...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2 data in 1 request then you can use max 1500 virtual users if you are not repeating your data.

If it is fine then add 2 columns in csv file like REF1 and REF2 and each column will have 1500 data. Then you can use ${REF1} and ${REF2} in your requests.

Answer (score 0):

If it takes you 3 minutes to add 3000 values with 3000 users and you need this to be done in 1 minute I can think of 2 possible causes:

1. Your application cannot process the requests faster. You can try increasing number of threads i.e. to 9000 in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and see whether it helps or not. If you still have this 3 minutes processing time - it's your application to blame
2. JMeter is not capable of sending requests fast enough.

   - First of all make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
   - Then make sure to monitor the health of the machine where JMeter is running using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) as JMeter must have enough headroom to operate
   - If a single machine cannot produce 3000 requests per minute - you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)